# How to fix my for loop from returning all the same variables

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm working on this ***for loop*** where I imported the data from a CSV file. I am attempting to assign different variables to different dates. However, my for loop keeps returning only 1 variable.

Ideally it should be something like this below:

```
     Date    mr 
    1/1/11   23
    1/1/11   23
    1/2/11   100
    1/2/11   100
    1/3/11   ok
    1/3/11   ok
```

I've tried the following code:

```py
 mr= []

     for i in df['Date']:
         if str(df[['Date']]) == '1/1/11':
             mr.append('23')
         elif str(df[['Date']]) == '1/2/11':
             mr.append('100')
         else:
             mr.append('ok')

 df['mr'] = mr
```

What i got was:

```
    Date     mr 
    1/1/11   ok
    1/1/11   ok
    1/2/11   ok
    1/2/11   ok
    1/3/11   ok
    1/3/11   ok
```

Can someone tell me how to assign each variable to each date? Thank you

Comment: Use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to explain beyond the documentation I linked to. Drop the `if` checks and use a dictionary for the replacements

Comment: yeap i was hoping for a more comprehensive answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job

```
mapping = {
    '1/1/11': '23', 
    '1/2/11': '100', 
    '1/3/11': 'ok'
}

df['mr'] = df['Date'].map(mapping)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop also you can access the dataframe values.`str(df[['Date']])` gives string formatted Date column of Dataframe. So you are getting values as `ok` only.
Check the following working code snippet

```py
mr= []

for i in df['Date']:
    if str(i) == '1/1/11':
        mr.append('23')
    elif str(i) == '1/2/11':
        mr.append('100')
    else:
        mr.append('ok')

df['mr'] = mr
```